# ExecutorService behaviour when total number of task are less then number of threads allocated

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

If I create ExecutorService with thread pool size 10(using newFixedThreadPool) and initially only 5 tasks are running, in this case ExecutorService create 10 threads and 5 will be ideal or only 5 thread will be created.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)` then you will create a thread pool of size `nThreads`. All threads will be created and will be idle if they have nothing to do.

ExecutorSerivce creates the constructor of [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor-int-int-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue-) with the parameters:

- `corePoolSize` is `nThreads`
- `maximumPoolSize` is `nThreads`
- `keepAliveTime` is `0`
- `unit` is `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS`
- `workQueue` is a "unbound" queue [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)
  (The actual bound is: `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which normal programs should never reach)

---

If you don't want that, you will have to create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` yourself.

Note that you have to use a `queue` with an upper-bound (that is actually reached when you run your software normally), else no new `Threads` will be created - because that only happens if the queue is full.

Answer (score 0):

In this case 10 thread will be created in thread pool. Then 5 thread will be assigned to task. and other 5 will be waiting for new task to come up.

Apart from this if any of 5 running thread is completed, it will be return to pool.